# Regex Named Capture for multiple numbers in string 

Tags: c#, regex

Given a string

```
 var testData = "1234 test string 987 more test";
```

I want to be able to use a regex to pull out 1234 and 987.  As far as I could tell using

```
 var reg = new Regex(@"?<numbers>\d+");
```

should do what I want but when I say

```
 var match = reg.match(testData);
```

I would think that

```
 Assert.AreEqual(match.Groups["numbers"].Captures.Count(), 2);
```

but it's only 1.  What am I doing wrong?  Intuition tells me that the

```
 ?<group>
```

means there can only be 0 or 1 of these values. Should I not be using a named group?

```
 *<group>
```

doesn't seem to work in the regex builder in visual studio but I did not try it in my tests.

Comment: As an aside, be careful about this kind of intuition around regex symbols, since the meaning of symbols such as `?` and `*` is highly dependent on context.  For instance, `(?:[:\b---[-]])??(?<b-b>\b)?` is a valid (though contrived) .NET regular expression where each `\b`, `-`, `?`, and `:` has a different meaning.  The `?` in `(?<group>.)` has an entirely different meaning from, and no relation to, the `?` in `.?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why didn't you use the pattern string as below:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d+");
```

and then get the numbers by:

```
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(testData);
```

After that, the `matches` variable contains 2 *Match* value which represent for *1234* and *987*.

You also use the assert as:

```
Assert.AreEqual(matches.Count, 2);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I will give that a try. I guess I was trying to use more features of regex that I haven't used yet.

Comment: how would you achieve this with the named capture?

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"([\d]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++) {
            Group groupObj = matchResults.Groups[i];
            if (groupObj.Success) {
                // matched text: groupObj.Value
                // match start: groupObj.Index
                // match length: groupObj.Length
            } 
        }
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Or: `foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+")) { /* matched text: m.Value */ }`  ;)